# Electric Cooktop Griddle?

Tags: griddle

I recently bought a house that has an oven with an electric 4-burner flat cooktop (estimated circa 1970s/80s), as well as an additional electric 4-burner cooktop. What I'm wondering, is there an electric flat top griddle on the market to replace the standalone cooktop? I'm envisioning the equivalent to a short order single large cooking surface for things like pancakes, fried rice, etc.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Like this? [Griddle](http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Electric-Countertop-Griddle-c101p25340.html?st-t=google_shopping&vt-k=&vt-pti=90020057455&gclid=Cj0KEQjwrJ2tBRD13N7T5u7k9I8BEiQA5APAAAFPgoFM_61pPqeSQWrXIb3BGFlY0nerSuB1fiO2hD4aAlKj8P8HAQ)

Comment: It sounds like you want something that actually fits into the counter the same way the original cooktop does? So it doesn't really matter what you're replacing, you're just asking if there exist large griddle cooktops for home use?